# Unable to add or search any record in sqlite database logcat shows inactive input connection

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to do CRUD operation in android. But I'm not able to do any operation.  On performing any operation logcat shows inactive input connection.  Suggest me someway to get my app work.

## code on creating DB and adding, searching and deleting records

```
  public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productDB.db";
private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";
public static final String COLUMN_QUANTITY = "quantity";


public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
             TABLE_PRODUCTS + "("
             + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME 
             + " TEXT," + COLUMN_QUANTITY + " INTEGER" + ")";
      db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,int newVersion)
{

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addProduct(Product product) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.getProductName());
    values.put(COLUMN_QUANTITY, product.getQuantity());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
    db.close();
 public Product findProduct(String productname) {
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " +       COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " =  \"" + productname + "\"";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Product product = new Product();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        product.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        product.setProductName(cursor.getString(1));
        product.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
        cursor.close();
    } else {
        product = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return product;
}

public boolean deleteProduct(String productname) {

    boolean result = false;

    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " =  \"" + productname + "\"";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Product product = new Product();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        product.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        db.delete(TABLE_PRODUCTS, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(product.getID()) });
        cursor.close();
        result = true;
    }
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: some one helpto reslove dis issue

Comment: Please provide a stack trace.

Comment: is der any way to improve my code ?

Comment: my logcat error:

 01-27 08:28:58.256: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27735): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
01-27 08:28:58.256: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27735): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection